# How convert date in words?

Tags: .net

I want to convert date in english words in Vb.net.
For example: 26 May,2008 to Twenty sixth May 2008

What will be best approch, is any function in datetime data type exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably the best approach:-

```
private static string[] dayText = new string[]
{"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eighth",
 "Nineth", "Tenth", "Eleventh", "Twelveth", "Thirteenth", "Fourteenth", "Fifteenth",
  "Sixteenth", "Seventeenth", "Eighteenth", "Nineteenth", "Twentieth", "Twenty first",
 "Twenty second", "Twenty third", "Twenty fourth", "Twenty fifth", "Twenty sixth",
 "Twenty seventh", "Twenty eighth", "Twenty nineth", "Thirtieth", "Thirty first"};

public static string DayInWords(int day)
{
    //assertion code here
    return dayText[day-1];
}

...
string result = DayInWords(myDate.Day) + myDate.ToString(" MMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any built in function. But there are only 31 days to consider. It would be easy enough to construct a function which manually replaced 1 to 31 with words. Then append the month and year, as in:

```
Function foobar(ByVal mydate As Date) As String

Dim result As String = ""
Select Case mydate.Day
    Case 1
        result = "First"
        Case 2
            result = "Second"
        Case 3
            result = "Third"

        ... etc ...

        Case 31
        result = "Thirty-First"
End Select
Return result & " " & mydate.ToString("MMMM yyyy")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed given the small amount of possible numbers, hardcoding them is probably the easiest soultion. But if you don't want to do that, take a look at these resources:

http://xl.barasch.com/cCo11432.htm
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_number_to_words2.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I use (credit to unknown author):

```
public static string DateToText(DateTime dt, bool includeTime, bool isUK)
{
    string[] ordinals =
    {
       "first day",
       "second day",
       "third day",
       "fourth day",
       "fifth day",
       "sixth day",
       "seventh day",
       "eighth day",
       "ninth day",
       "tenth day",
       "eleventh day",
       "twelfth day",
       "thirteenth day",
       "fourteenth day",
       "fifteenth day",
       "sixteenth day",
       "seventeenth day",
       "eighteenth day",
       "nineteenth day",
       "twentieth day",
       "twenty first day",
       "twenty second day",
       "twenty third day",
       "twenty fourth day",
       "twenty fifth day",
       "twenty sixth day",
       "twenty seventh day",
       "twenty eighth day",
       "twenty ninth day",
       "thirtieth day",
       "thirty first day"

    };

    int day = dt.Day;
    int month = dt.Month;
    int year = dt.Year;
    DateTime dtm = new DateTime(1, month, 1);
    string date;

    if (isUK)
    {
        //date = "This " + ordinals[day - 1] + " of " + dtm.ToString("MMMM") + " " + NumberToText(year, true);

        date = "this " + ordinals[day - 1] + " of " + dtm.ToString("MMMM") + ", " + NumberToText(year, true);
    }
    else
    {
        date = dtm.ToString("MMMM") + " " + ordinals[day - 1] + " " + NumberToText(year, false);
    }

    if (includeTime)
    {
        int hour = dt.Hour;
        int minute = dt.Minute;
        string ap = "AM";

        if (hour >= 12)
        {
            ap = "PM";
            hour = hour - 12;
        }

        if (hour == 0) hour = 12;
        string time = NumberToText(hour, false);
        if (minute > 0) time += " " + NumberToText(minute, false);
        time += " " + ap;
        date += ", " + time;
    }

    return date;
}

public static string NumberToText(int number, bool isUK)
{
    if (number == 0) return "Zero";
    string and = isUK ? "" : ""; // removed the and from the text - bevan 09/16/2019
    //string and = isUK ? "and " : ""; // deals with UK or US numbering
    if (number == -2147483648) return "Minus Two Billion One Hundred " + and +
    "Forty Seven Million Four Hundred " + and + "Eighty Three Thousand " +
    "Six Hundred " + and + "Forty Eight";
    int[] num = new int[4];
    int first = 0;
    int u, h, t;
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    if (number < 0)
    {
        sb.Append("Minus ");
        number = -number;
    }
    string[] words0 = { "", "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ", "nine " };
    string[] words1 = { "ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ", "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ", "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ", "nineteen " };
    string[] words2 = { "twenty-", "thirty-", "forty-", "fifty-", "sixty-", "seventy-", "eighty-", "ninety-" };
    string[] words3 = { "thousand ", "million ", "billion " };
    num[0] = number % 1000;           // units
    num[1] = number / 1000;
    num[2] = number / 1000000;
    num[1] = num[1] - 1000 * num[2];  // thousands
    num[3] = number / 1000000000;     // billions
    num[2] = num[2] - 1000 * num[3];  // millions
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (num[i] != 0)
        {
            first = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = first; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (num[i] == 0) continue;
        u = num[i] % 10;              // ones
        t = num[i] / 10;
        h = num[i] / 100;             // hundreds
        t = t - 10 * h;               // tens
        if (h > 0) sb.Append(words0[h] + "Hundred ");
        if (u > 0 || t > 0)
        {
            if (h > 0 || i < first) sb.Append(and);
            if (t == 0)
                sb.Append(words0[u]);
            else if (t == 1)
                sb.Append(words1[u]);
            else
                sb.Append(words2[t - 2] + words0[u]);
        }
        if (i != 0) sb.Append(words3[i - 1]);
    }
    return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).