# cocoa: speech and time

Tags: cocoa, time, speech

I'm building an app that a part of will speak the time. However, when I pass in my date strings (like 10/24/11) to the NSSpeechSynthesizer it will speak them literally, as "one, zero, slash two four slash one one", same with a timestamp, "eight colon one one colon colon", etc. etc.

I looked at the NSSpeechSynthesizer docs and I guess I'd have to work with the phonemesFromText method but that seems like a lot of grunt work to get the app to speak the time and date smoothly. Is there a quicker method?

Thanks

Comment: You could roll your own date-to-speakable-text function, so that the date 10/24/11 translates to "on the tenth of October, 2011" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I will be rolling my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
@implementation MDAppController
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSDateFormatter *dateParser = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]
        initWithDateFormat:@"%m/%d/%y" allowNaturalLanguage:YES] autorelease];

    NSDate *date = [dateParser dateFromString:@"10/24/11"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

   NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"string == %@", string);
    // prints "October 24, 2011"

    NSSpeechSynthesizer *alex = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc]
           initWithVoice:[NSSpeechSynthesizer defaultVoice]];
    [alex setDelegate:self];
    [alex startSpeakingString:string];
}

- (void)speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender
                   didFinishSpeaking:(BOOL)finishedSpeaking {
    if (finishedSpeaking) [sender autorelease];
}
@end
```

Basically, this is using 2 `NSDateFormatter`s: one to "translate" the string representation of a date into an actual `NSDate` object, and then another to translate that `NSDate` back into a more desirable string representation.

Obviously, you'll need to adjust the `dateParser` format to fit your expected input string type. (Preferably, you could just use an input date rather than the string representation of it).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to and -[NSString stringWithFormat:] construct a spoken sentence as your string, then speak *that*?

Comment: You still need some way to go from 10 --> "tenth", and 2011 --> "two thousand and eleven" or "twenty-eleven" or whatever

Comment: Correct. That's a separate (even if related) problem from this one. Here's an SO answer to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666164/how-convert-date-in-words

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that's a great tip, also didn't know about NSDateComponents, nice stuff.